# How to use trigger mysql for filter

Tags: mysql

I have a code trigger before insert in MySQLfor filter data but it doesn't work. This is the logical of my code, if new.suhu_udara > 30 and new.suhu_udara - old.suhu_udara <10 then set new.suhu_udara = null

```
USE `cuaca_maritim`;
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cuaca_maritim.filter$$
USE `cuaca_maritim`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `filter` BEFORE INSERT ON data_cuaca` FOR EACH ROW
if( new.suhu_udara < 21.5 or new.kelembaban_udara < 22 or new.tekanan_udara < 1002.4) then
Set new.suhu_udara = null ;
elseif ( new.suhu_udara > 37.6 or new.kelembaban_udara > 100 or new.tekanan_udara >1018.9 or new.kecepatan_angin > 44) then
Set new.kelembaban_udara = null ;
end if$$
DELIMITER ;
USE `cuaca_maritim`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cuaca_maritim.data_cuaca_AFTER_UPDATE$$
USE `cuaca_maritim`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER  `cuaca_maritim`.`data_cuaca_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `data_cuaca` FOR EACH ROW
if ( old.suhu_udara - new.suhu_udara > 10) then 
set new.suhu_udara=null ;
end if
 $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can you help mex this code? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not using proper trigger functionality. In Insert Trigger what is OLD.suhu_udara  ?

OLD. values are only in the update queries.

Please check trigger functionalities, I think you should use Update here.

Comment: In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated. But I try use old.value in before update it doesn't work